# No internet connection after setuping OpenConnect server on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev vpn0
ip addr add 192.168.2.2/24 dev vpn0

# systemctl restart ocserv
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

```
#ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:00:04:c4:b9:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 66.42.108.48/23 brd 66.42.109.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 85512sec preferred_lft 85512sec
    inet6 2001:19f0:6001:5689:5400:4ff:fec4:b9c3/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591893sec preferred_lft 604693sec
    inet6 fe80::5400:4ff:fec4:b9c3/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vpn0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 scope global vpn0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
#
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
#
# sysctl -a | grep forwarding | grep ipv4
net.ipv4.conf.all.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.bc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.vpn0.mc_forwarding = 0
#
```

openconnect config:

```
device = vpns0
tcp-port = 8443
ipv4-network = 192.168.2.0/24
route = default
```

Connection success. Internet do not works.
`ping 8.8.8.8` not work.
ping of vpn server if work.

Connection from Windows home to Linux VPS

Comment: Why are you creating the tun interface manually? Shouldn't openconnect/ocserv handle that by itself?

Comment: Yes I did it manually. Possible they should, but I just copied binaries to server